# File ReadLine Count

Tags: c#

I am trying to read from a file,the program goes through each line of the text file comparing the first 8 characters of the each line and joining these lines into one where the 8 characters are similar.See code:

```
 while ((line1 = fileread1.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            line2 = fileread2.ReadLine();
            while (line2 != null)
            {
                if (line1.Length >= 8 && line2.Length >= 8 &&
                    line1.Substring(0, 8) == line2.Substring(0, 8))
                {
                    //line2 = line2.Remove(0, 60);
                    line1 = line1 +" "+ line2;
                }
                line2 = fileread3.ReadLine();
                counter2++;
            }

            filewrite.WriteLine(line1);
            counter1++;
        }
```

Qusetion 1:

How can i get the count of fileread2 and assign it to fileread3,because i need every time the inner loop executes to reset the count of fileread3 to be the same as fileread2.

Question 2:

How do i write the combined lines as single line where the first 8 characters match.

Comment: o_O ?! say what ?! what are fileread[1..3] all about? and what is it you're actually trying to do?  Sounds like you can use a bit of LINQ, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do ...

Comment: The logic i used is to pick each line starting from the first and go through the rest of the lines making comparisons.thats the reason for fileread 1 and 2.fileread 3 loops through the entire lines and reaches end of file so i cant resuse it unless i reset it count.

Comment: @user3631366 It's not really a count, it's a seek position.  Also it looks like you are comparing multiple files? or do FileRead1..3 all point at the same file?

Comment: @James Barrass yes they are pointing at the same file but diffrent lines in this file.pick line 1 and compare to line 2 if the same combine if not pick line 3,then 4,5,6 etc in that sequence.

Comment: @TariqOndego How large are you expecting the files to be?

Comment: you're comparing each lines to all the ones after, or to all lines at all? (if line 1=2=4 , will you also get 2=1=4 and 4=1=2, or are you "removing" duplicates)

Comment: @JamesBarrass About 200mb.@Noctis duplicates is my other dilemma,the point is to compare each to all and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the comments what I understand is that you actually want to remove duplicates. Or, to be more specific, the lines that start with the same 8 characters.

If that's the case why not use a collection of keys to remember whether the string with the same 8 initial characters has not been already loaded.

E.g. you can have a collection (like List) where you add the 8 character substring. Then, before writing the line you first check if the substring is already in the collection. If it is then you know it's a duplicate and you don't write it.

Another option, if you want to calculate how many duplicates of a specific type there are, would be to use a Dictionary. When you have a duplicate of specific type you can then increase the counter in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group the data based on the first 8 characters, all you need is:

```
var groups = File.ReadLines(your_file_name).GroupBy(line => line.Substring(0, 8));
```

To count the elements you call `Count()` on the elements in the groups

```
groups.First().Count()
```

(you can also enumerate over `groups` via `foreach (var group in groups)`..)

The group result will contain the complete line from the file. If you don't want the "key" (i.e. the first 8 characters) in the result, you can use the overload of GroupBy

```
var groups = File.ReadLines(your_file_name).GroupBy(line => line.Substring(0, 8), line => line.Substring(8));
```

In order to get new output with the "key" and the lines concatenated, you would use something like this:

```
var groups = File.ReadLines(input_file).GroupBy(line => line.Substring(0, 8), line => line.Substring(8));
File.WriteAllLines(output_file, groups.Select(group => string.Format("{0}{1}", group.Key, string.Join(string.Empty, group))));
```

Comment: How would i write these groups into a text file? one group per line?

Comment: Do you just want to concanate the strings with the keys? i.e. if you have "my name is john" and "my name doe" the output should be "my name is john doe" or "my name is john my name doe". Let me know and I'll complete the answer.

Comment: it should be "my name is john doe"

Comment: the file has two headers,how would i skip these two headers with ReadLines because they don't meet 8 length character condition.I would then need to put the headers back on the output file.

Comment: well, you can use `.Skip()` and `.Take()`, also provided in the LINQ library. Or you can rewrite the logic, so instead of `GroupBy` you actually `foreach` over `File.ReadLines`.

Comment: well,foreach is the logic that i was using before i saw yours,..your logic is much neat and consumes less resources.

Comment: foreach in itself doesn't consume memory. `ReadLines` only returns one line at a time, so it should be just fine to use. Otherwise, go with `Skip` and `Take`. you can read about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I have tried both Skip and Take but the problem is in the Substring(0,8),i keep getting error "Index and length must refer to a location within the string"

Answer (score 0):

Since you have large files, probably `File.ReadAllLines` is not an option for you. You can declare the following methods (we need to work with `Stream`, since `StreamReader` doesn't have `Position` property):

```
public static string ReadLine(Stream stream)
{
    return ReadLine(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
}

public static string ReadLine(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
{
    List<byte> lineBytes = new List<byte>();
    while (stream.Position < stream.Length)
    {
        byte b = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
        if (b == 0x0a)
            break;
        if (b == 0x0d)
            continue;
        lineBytes.Add(b);
    }
    return encoding.GetString(lineBytes.ToArray());
}
```

Sample code:

```
string sourceFileName = "input.txt";
string targetFileName = "output.txt";

using (StreamWriter targetWriter = new StreamWriter(targetFileName))
using (FileStream sourceStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFileName))
{
    HashSet<string> processedKeys = new HashSet<string>();
    while (sourceStream.Position < sourceStream.Length)
    {
        string line = ReadLine(sourceStream);
        if (line.Length < 8)
            targetWriter.WriteLine(line);
        else
        {
            string key = line.Substring(0, 8);
            if (processedKeys.Contains(key))
                continue;
            targetWriter.Write(line);
            long backupPosition = sourceStream.Position;
            while (sourceStream.Position < sourceStream.Length)
            {
                string dupLine = ReadLine(sourceStream);
                if (dupLine.Length < 8)
                    continue;
                string dupKey = dupLine.Substring(0, 8);
                if (dupKey == key)
                    targetWriter.Write(" " + dupLine);
            }
            sourceStream.Position = backupPosition;
            targetWriter.WriteLine();
            processedKeys.Add(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ReadLines` works differently than `ReadAllLines` since *When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned;* as per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Any reason to use the `ReadLine` method you provided over the one in `File`?

Comment: @Default I need `Position` property to be backed and restored while searching for duplicates. I don't see how it can be achieved with `ReadLines`. And regarding sample code you provided: `GroupBy` will cause full traverse of `ReadLines`, so there is no difference between `ReadLines` and `ReadAllLines`.